# Photoimage cannot load image on imported class

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a program with Tkinter, I decided to use image buttons for easier to interact but PhotoImage by somehow not worked.
The code example of the script contain image button:

```
from tkinter import *

class test:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        img = PhotoImage(r'E:\v1.1\import.png')
        b1 = Button(self.master, image = img).pack()
```

The script that contain source code that will load the above script:

```
from test2 import *
maingui = Tk() 
gui = test(maingui) 
maingui.mainloop()
```

By somehow the image is not loaded, leaving very small button. Anyone know what have I wrong?

EDIT 1: I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function) (mentioned by acw1668) and edit the code of the first script but its not worked

```
from tkinter import *

class test:
    def __init__(self,master):
        global img
        self.master = master
        img = PhotoImage('E:\\v1.1\\import.png')
        imglabel = Label(image=img)
        imglabel.image = img
        imglabel.pack()

        b1 = Button(self.master, image = img).pack()
```

The results is the same as you can see on the link
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo1XH.png

EDIT 2: I have tried to add self. into img and imglabel but its not worked too.

```
from tkinter import *

class test:
    def __init__(self,master):
    # I cannot global self.img so I have to delete it
        self.master = master
        self.img = PhotoImage('E:\\v1.1\\import.png')
        self.imglabel = Label(image=img)
        self.imglabel.image = self.img
        self.imglabel.pack()

        self.b1 = Button(self.master, image = self.img).pack()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: @acw1668 Its not worked, I have tried all ways on that post and none of them worked.

Comment: Please show what you've tried from that other answer, or we'll have to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @BryanOakley I will post a new code I recreate from the mentioned post when I'm at home immediately

Comment: @BryanOakley I have added the new code on EDIT1

Comment: You aren't saving a reference to `imglabel`.

Comment: @BryanOakley is close.  The problem is that you need to save a reference to `img`.  Tk doesn't do that automatically.  Just change `img` to `self.img`.

Comment: @TimRoberts: they are already attempting to save a reference to `img`. However, they are saving it by attatching it to another object that is not being saved.

Comment: Tkinter automatically has the parent widget (root in this case) take a reference to each child widget.  So, `self.master` will hold the `imglabel` reference.  But `imglabel` doesn't take a reference to the `PhotoImage`.  There was another question about this exact behavior earlier today.

Comment: @TimRoberts Its still not worked, I have updated EDIT 2 on my original post, can you come and check what step I was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `PhotoImage` from

```py
PhotoImage('E:\\v1.1\\import.png')
```

to

```py
PhotoImage( file = 'E:\\v1.1\\import.png')
```

Comment: You certainly had 'em going @Rotmegax! Happy coding.